# What does it mean when a struct has no identity?

Tags: c#

I read  several threads on here about structs (one about mutable structs) and I keep reading about how a struct should have no identity.

What exactly is a lack of identity in a struct? I am guessing it would be like a number, e.g. 5, not having a context (5 what?). Whereas client would be someone expecting a service, and thus there is an identity. Am I thinking correctly?

I know the technical differences and how structs are thread safe (as long as they can't be mutated, but I can still write methods to mutate state), they have new copies everytime they are passed into a method, etc...

Comment: Care to cite a thread talking about structs/identity?

Comment: Sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs is the thread I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that the only data you have about a struct is the values is stores - there's no difference between one "5" and another "5". Compare this with a class:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Jon");
Person person2 = new Person("Jon");
Person person3 = person2;
```

Now `person1` and `person2` have references to distinct objects, although they both contain the same data. `person2` and `person3` both refer to the *same* objects. With structs this distinction doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Struct is a value type, so it just represents a value. An Id would only be useful to create a reference to it, in which case it is better off being a class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're more or less influenced by [Evans' book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), where he distinguishes Entities and Value objects.