# Is there something like List<String, Int32, Int32> (multidimensional generic list)

Tags: c#, list, collections, generic-list

I need something similar to `List<String, Int32, Int32>`. List only supports one type at a time, and Dictionary only two at a time. Is there a clean way to do something like the above (a multidimensional generic list/collection)?

Comment: The duplication of Int32 is interesting.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to associate two different numbers semantically with one string, which will then be used to render data in a view.

Comment: I think @Alex has `java` background such as me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best way is to create a container for it ie a class

```
public class Container
{
    public int int1 { get; set; }
    public int int2 { get; set; }
    public string string1 { get; set; }
}
```

then in the code where you need it

```
List<Container> myContainer = new List<Container>();
```

Comment: +1 since it doesn't require a .Net4 tuple and can be trivially implemented with a class, but -1 because you should avoid public fields on a class. Implement as a property and use simple `{get; set;}` instead.

Comment: You will probably need to override Equals and GetHashCode too

Comment: type Container should be an immutable struct since it only represent values.

Comment: Depending on the implementation needs for Alex, he can decide if he needs an Equals to, and also decide Class Vs Struct, again depending on the needs of his project, however if its just for storing values, then a struct would make sense.

Answer (score 13):

In .NET 4 you can use `List<Tuple<String, Int32, Int32>>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on .NET 3.5, but I'll keep this in mind for 4.0!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do this til C# 3.0, use Tuples if you can use C# 4.0 as mentioned in other answers.

However In C# 3.0 - create an `Immutable structure` and wrap all types' insances within the structure and pass the structure type as generic type argument to your list.

```
public struct Container
{
    public string String1 { get; private set; }
    public int Int1 { get; private set; }
    public int Int2 { get; private set; }

    public Container(string string1, int int1, int int2)
        : this()
    {
        this.String1 = string1;
        this.Int1 = int1;
        this.Int2 = int2;
    }
}

//Client code
IList<Container> myList = new List<Container>();
myList.Add(new Container("hello world", 10, 12));
```

If you're curious why create immutable structs - [checkout here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you need a struct with two integers stored in a dictionary with a string key.

```
struct MyStruct
{
   int MyFirstInt;
   int MySecondInt;
}

...

Dictionary<string, MyStruct> dictionary = ...
```