# Why does Unit.Pixel() only take an integer parameter, but new Unit() has a default return type of Pixel and handles doubles?

Tags: c#

Going through my code, I was hoping to remove instances where I do this:

```
Height = new Unit(doubleValue);
```

where Height was representing a value in pixels.

I didn't like having to say new everywhere, it felt like I should be able to just modify height's value, but it is read-only.

As such, I stumbled upon Unit.Pixel() and Unit.Percentage(). The percentage method takes a double, but the pixel method only handles integers.

Is there some big reason behind this, an oversight, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Is it standard to create a new unit every time I wish to change height's value?

EDIT: For reference,

[Unit Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyk4f9a5.aspx)

[Pixel Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.pixel.aspx)

Comment: what component is that???  Height in a Form or Control is a simple int

Comment: @Daniel I think it is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit

Comment: @rohan - not my department, luckily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx) is a struct and therefore is [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs).  You will need to create a new instance each time you want change the height value.

In web development, sizes are not always measured in pixels, there are many [UnitTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unittype.aspx)

```
Unit.Pixel(int n) // Pixels are represented as integer values.
```

I guess that the Constructor that accepts a double was provided for convenience.

You can do a simple test

```
var x = new Unit(5.0);
var y = Unit.Pixel(5);

Assert.AreEqual(x, y); // returns true
```

Comment: But wait, if I have a Height with value 5 and type pixel, it is perfectly fine to say height = Unit.Pixel(10); This changes the value of height, no?

Comment: When I call new Unit(200.5, UnitType.Pixel); I am given an object which says its value is 200.5 pixels. Is this to say that if I use Unit.Pixel(200) I would see no visual differences? (Assuming no code is dependent on the double value and its only necessary for displaying to the screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify pixels in double in the browser, and it really make difference when browser zoom is used.