# Concat a DateTime

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, datetimepicker, timepicker

On a wpf application i have a DatePicker, and, a TimePicker ( from the Extended WPF Toolkit).
These two contrôls return a DateTime Value.

I would like to store the result of this two control in a one DateTime variable.

I tried :

```
myNewEvenement.dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value;
myNewEvenement.dDate += (DateTime)TimePicker_Heure.Value;
```

But i cannot compile this code.

Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.Add(TimeSpan value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) method to create new `DateTime` object (you can't change value of existing `DateTime` struct, because it is immutable):

```
myNewEvenement.dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Value
                           .Add(TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

Or more readable:

```
DateTime date = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Value;
TimeSpan time = TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay;
myNewEvenement.dDate = date.Add(time);
```

Comment: I don't have a TimeOfDay property on a TimePicker :(

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni that is a property of TimePicker.Value (which is DateTime)

Comment: Yes but i don't have the .TimeOfDay on TimePicker.Value

Comment: I need to use Value twice ! TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni I thought TimePicker.Value has type `DateTime`. Is it `Nullable<DateTime>`? If yes, then you are right. Use `TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay`

Answer (score 1):

The TimePicker's `Value` is a `DateTime`. Since you want to add the time to the date, simply add the TimeOfDay property of the time picker's value when adding, such as:

```
myNewEvenement.dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value;
myNewEvenement.dDate += TimePicker_Heure.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I don't have a TimeOfDay property on a TimePicker.Value :(

Comment: The Extended WPF Toolkit documetation says that `TimePicker_Heure.Value` is a `DateTime`, and a `DateTime` instance has a `TimeOfDay` property.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a struct, hence it is [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs). You can create a new `DateTime` by using `DateTime.Add` with the appropriate `TimeSpan`:

```
long ticks = ((DateTime)TimePicker_Heure.Value).Ticks;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks);
myNewEvenement.dDate = myNewEvenement.dDate.Add(ts);
```

or directly via `DateTime.AddTicks`

```
myNewEvenement.dDate = myNewEvenement.dDate.AddTicks(ticks);
```