# How to handle array bounds out in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any way to handle error index out of bounds in C

i just want to to know, please explain it in context of this example.
if i enter a string more than 20 char i get *** stack smashing detected ***: ./upper1 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

```
main()
{
char st[20];
int i;

 /* accept a string */
 printf("Enter a string : ");
 gets(st);

 /* display it in upper case */
 for ( i = 0 ; st[i] != '\0';  i++)
  if ( st[i] >= 'a'  &&  st[i] <= 'z' )
       putchar( st[i] - 32);
  else
       putchar( st[i]);
}
```

I want to handle those and stop them and display a custom message as done in Java's Exception Handling. Is it possible ? If yes how

Thanks in advance

Comment: `C` doesn't check array index out of bound.

Comment: `gets()` has been deprecated in C11. It's always been dangerous anyway. Don't use it; use `fgets()` instead. And no, there's no way to handle out of bounds issue in Cother than programmatically ensuring it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the original question: there is no way to handle *implicitly* out-of-bound array indexes in C. You should add that check *explicitly* in your code or you should *prove* (or at least be absolutely sure) that it does not happen. Beware of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), it can hurt a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

Remember that C arrays don't "know" their size at *runtime*. You should know and manage that size, especially when passing arrays (which become decayed into pointers). Read also about flexible array members in `struct`-s (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485347/841108)).

BTW, your code is poor taste. First, the `char st[20];` is really too small these days: an input line can have really a hundred of characters (I often have terminal emulators wider than 80 columns). So make it e.g.

```
 char st[128];
```

Then, as every one told you, [gets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) is dangerous, it is documented as "Never use this function". Take the habit of reading the documentation of every function that you dare use.

I would suggest to always clear such a string buffer with

```
memset (st, 0, sizeof st);
```

You should at the very least use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), but read the documentation first. You'll need to handle the failure case.

Also, your conversion to upper-case is specific to ASCII (and some other encodings). It won't work on old [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) machine. And it is unreadable. So use [isalpha(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) to detect letters (in ASCII or other single-byte encoding); but in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) it is more complex, since some letters -eg [cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) ones- are encoded on *several* bytes). My family name (СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ when spelt in Russian) contains an Ы -which is a single letter called [yery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yery) - whose UTF-8 encoding for the capital letter is 0xD0 0xAB on *two* bytes. You'll need an UTF-8 library like [unistring](http://unistring.sourceforge.net/) to handle these. And use [toupper(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html) to convert (e.g. ASCII) letters to upper-case.

Notice that your `main` function is wrongly defined. It should return an `int` and preferably be declared as `int main(int argc, char**argv)`.

At last, on Posix systems, the "right" way to read a line is to use the [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function. It can read a line as wide as permitted by system resources (so it might read a line of a million characters on my machine). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108).

Regarding exceptions, C don't really have these (so most programmers take the habit to have functions giving some error code). However, for non-local jumps consider [setjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) to be used with *great caution*. (In C++, you have exceptions and they are related to destructors).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). You absolutely need to learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) and you also should use a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  you must use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.  In fact, `gets()` is officially deprecated and should never, ever be used, because it is impossible to use safely as you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not directly possible to detect that the user has written out of bounds it, we can add some logic to make sure to throw an error without crashing.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char user_input [USERINPUT_MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < USERINPUT_MAX; ++i)
    {
        // read the character 
        // check for enter key, if enter break out of loop after adding null at end
        // if not enter,store it in array 
    }
    if (i == USERINPUT_MAX)
    {
        printf ("you have exceeded the character range");
    }
}
```

I guess you get the idea of how to handle such situations from user input.