# How to calloc() 25 byte exactly

Tags: c, memory, malloc, byte, calloc

I want to calloc 25 bytes of memory exactly. In this case, msg_len = 5 bytes, since that is what the input is. This is the code I have:

```
  int full_msg_size = 20 + msg_len;
  printf("full_msg_size: %d\n", full_msg_size);
  void *full_msg = calloc(full_msg_size, sizeof(char));
  printf("size of full_msg: %d\n", (int*)sizeof(full_msg));
```

This is what prints out:

full_msg_size: 25
size of full_msg: 8

But I want size of full_msg to equal 25 bytes just like full_msg_size.

I also want all the memory spaces initialized to zero.

Can anyone tell me how to calloc/malloc this properly?

Thanks

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so you just can write 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your post, it seems that you really want to determine the ***length*** of a string contained by a variable, as opposed to the ***size*** of the variable.  `sizeof` when applied to a pointer, will tell you the size of the address, not the length of the string.  If you need to determine the ***length*** of a string at runtime, use the function `strlen`:

```
`int len = strlen(some_str)`
```

You may be getting ***full_msg_size: 25 size of full_msg: 8*** because sizeof
is returning the size of the address of `full_msg`.

So, your function:

```
printf("size of full_msg: %d\n", (int*)sizeof(full_msg));
```

Should be:

```
printf("length of full_msg: %d\n", strlen(full_msg));
```

if you want to *want to calloc 25 bytes of memory exactly*:

```
char *full_msg = {0};
full_msg = calloc(25, 1); //all space initialized to 0     
//or you can also use:  
full_msg = malloc(25);
```

full_msg now has memory for exactly 25 bytes, (but one needs to be used for '\0')

The `sizeof` operator when used on a `char *str`, returns to you the size of a `char *`, which is just an address.

***Note***:  The size of an address (or pointer) will not always be 8 bytes *just because you are running a 64 bit machine*, it depends on what the application is compiled to:  32bit or 64bit.  i.e., For a 32 but application, size of an address is 4 bytes, for a 64 bit application, it will be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely allocating the correct number of bytes but you are asking how big a pointer to a void is. And on a 64 bit box it will very likely be 8 bytes. If it failed to allocate the amount of memory you asked for then full_message would have the value NULL.

Answer (score 3):

The `sizeof` operator is (almost always) a *compile-time* operator (exception: [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s). So the `sizeof` some pointer is always the same (on your machine, it is always 8) and does not depend of the size passed to some `malloc` or `calloc` function.

Given a `malloc`-ed or `calloc`-ed pointer, there is no portable way to know the size requested at its allocation time. You should keep that size somewhere! You might use a *flexible array member* like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485347/841108) if you wanted to keep that dynamic size inside the allocated structure. You often keep the size elsewhere i.e. in some variable (`full_msg_size` in your case).

So your `calloc` is working (BTW, you should test it against failure).

```
void *full_msg = calloc(full_msg_size, 1);
if (!full_msg) {perror("calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

But you *cannot use* `sizeof` to compute the *runtime* size of the allocated zone.

Comment: `sizeof` is only sort-of a compile-time thing in C. C is weird.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing size of pointer which will be 8 bytes in the case of 64-bit machines.

Comment: _size of pointer which will be 8 bytes in the case of 64-bit machines_.  Not always true.  Only if the target for the application using the code is compiled to be 64bit.  Many applications, even when built on a 64 bit machine are built as 32bit.  In that case, size of an address (pointer) will be 32 bits or 4 bytes.

Comment: Yes, i was also referring to the same point only but did not mention it explicitly.