# Segmentation fault 11 in following code. How to avoid overflow?

Tags: c

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char* hostname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    hostname = getClientHostName("122.205.26.34");
    printf("%s\n", hostname);
    free(hostname);
}

char* getClientHostName(char* client_ip) {

    char hostnames[5][2];
    hostnames[0][0] = "122.205.26.34";
    hostnames[0][1] = "aaaaa";
    hostnames[1][0] = "120.205.36.30";
    hostnames[1][1] = "bbbbb";
    hostnames[2][0] = "120.205.16.36";
    hostnames[2][1] = "ccccc";
    hostnames[3][0] = "149.205.36.46";
    hostnames[3][1] = "dddddd";
    hostnames[4][0] = "169.205.36.33";
    hostnames[4][1] = "eeeeee";
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(hostnames[i][0], client_ip))
            return (char*)hostnames[i][1];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Beginner in C.

I am not sure if there would be a better way to implement what I am trying to implement. The code is self-explanatory. Is there any way that I can predefine the size of hostname, using some general size of IP addresses, to avoid seg fault? Is there a even better way where I don't have to hardcode the size?

Comment: Your code should not compile cleanly. Compile it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `*` to type definition `char * hostnames[5][2]`. This must be array of pointers, not simple `char`s. Another necessary change is `strcpy` instead of `=` in `strcpy( hostname, getClientHostName("122.205.26.34") );`.

PS: Always try to compile with 0 compiler warnings, not only 0 errors!

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the compiler errors and warnings you get:

```
const char* getClientHostName(const char* client_ip) {

    const char * hostnames[5][2];
    hostnames[0][0] = "122.205.26.34";
    hostnames[0][1] = "aaaaa";
    hostnames[1][0] = "120.205.36.30";
    hostnames[1][1] = "bbbbb";
    hostnames[2][0] = "120.205.16.36";
    hostnames[2][1] = "ccccc";
    hostnames[3][0] = "149.205.36.46";
    hostnames[3][1] = "dddddd";
    hostnames[4][0] = "169.205.36.33";
    hostnames[4][1] = "eeeeee";
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(hostnames[i][0], client_ip))
            return hostnames[i][1];
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char * hostname = getClientHostName("128.205.36.34");
    printf("%s\n", hostname);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a even better way where I don't have to hardcode the size?

Take the habit to compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings at all.

If you want to get genuine IP addresses, this is operating system specific (since standard [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) don't know about IP addresses; check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). On Linux you would use name service routines such as [getaddrinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) & [getnameinfo(3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html)) or the obsolete [gethostbyname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html).

If this is just an exercise without actual relationship to TCP/IP sockets (see [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), [ip(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)) you could store the table in some *global* array:

```
 struct myipentry_st {
   const char* myip_hostname;
   const char* myip_address;
 };
```

then define a [global](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) array containing them, with the convention  of terminating it by some `{NULL, NULL}` entry:

```
const struct myipentry_st mytable[] = {
    {"aaaaa", "122.205.26.34"},
    {"bbbb", "120.205.36.30"},
    /// etc
    {NULL, NULL} // end marker
};
```

You'll better have a *global* or [static variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) (not an [automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) one sitting on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) because you don't want to fill it on every call to your `getClientHostName`.

Then your lookup routine (inefficient, since in linear time) would be:

```
const char* getClientHostName(char* client_ip) {
   for (const struct myipentry_st* ent = mytable;
        ent->myip_hostname != NULL;
        ent++)
   // the if below is the only statement of the body of `for` loop
     if (!strcmp(ent->myip_address, client_ip))
         return ent->myip_hostname;
   // this happens after the `for` when nothing was found
   return NULL;
}
```

You could even declare that table as a [heap allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) pointer:

```
const struct myipentry_st**mytable;
```

then use `calloc` to allocate it and read its data from some text file.

Read the documentation of every [standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) or external function that you are using. Don't forget to check against failure (e.g. of `calloc`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551951/841108)). Avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) by appropriate calls to `free`. Use the debugger `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In the real world, you would have perhaps thousands of entries and you would perform the lookup many times (perhaps millions of times, e.g. once per every [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request in a web server or client). Then choose a better [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) ([hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) perhaps). Read some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But the thing is, I definitely could have implemented much better ways, and I can do that. But not in C. This is the first time I am coding in C. The very first time. Like, FIRST TIME. And I had a week to do this assignment. So I didn't get enough time to learn C. I am more comfortable with Java and to some extent Python, but C is very different. So right now I am just trying to make it work somehow.