# MPI_Reduce() program getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm starting my studies on parallel programming using C and the OpenMPI library. So everything looks a bit too complex right now.

I'm trying to do a Single Program Multiple Data that:
Master:
- Initialise an array
- Subdivide it
- Send bits of it of the same size to different processes (Slaves)
Slaves:
- processes change the array values and calculates the sum of all new elements
- Send changed array back to master
Master:
- Makes a collective communication to collect and sum the sums of the new values
- Print the five first elements of each new array received and the global sum of the new values.
- Print the time it took.

That's what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define ARRAYSIZE   16000000

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int myrank;
    char name[100];
    int result;
    int size = 0;
    int number;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Request request;
    int buffer;
    int count;
    double t1, t2;
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    int cells = ARRAYSIZE/size;
    float array[cells];

    if (myrank == 0) {
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();
        t2 = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &result);

        // ********************** INICIALIZANDO ARRAY **********************
        int     i;          /* loop variable */
        float   data[ARRAYSIZE];    /* the intial array */

        printf("Starting serial array example...\n");
        printf("Using array of %d floats. Requires %ld bytes\n",ARRAYSIZE,sizeof(data));

        /* Initialize the array */
        printf("Initializing array...\n");
        for(i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++)
          data[i] =  i * 1.0;

        /* Print a few sample results */
        printf("Sample results\n");
        printf("   data[1]=%e\n",  data[1]);
        printf("   data[100]=%e\n",  data[100]);
        printf("   data[1000]=%e\n",  data[1000]);
        printf("   data[10000]=%e\n",  data[10000]);
        printf("   data[100000]=%e\n",  data[100000]);
        printf("   data[1000000]=%e\n",  data[1000000]);
        printf("\nAll Done!\n");
        // ********************** ARRAY INICIALIZADO **********************

        MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
        printf("Total of tasks: %d", size);
        printf("Each task process %d cells", ARRAYSIZE/size);
        int cells = ARRAYSIZE/size;
        int id_task;
        for(id_task = 0; id_task < size; id_task++) {
            //float array[cells];
            int i=0;
            for(i=0; i<cells; i++)
                array[i] =  i * (id_task+1.0);
            MPI_Send(&array[id_task*cells], cells, MPI_FLOAT, id_task, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        printf("master: %d at processor: %s\n",myrank, name);

    }
    MPI_Recv(array, cells, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    int i;
    float resultado;
    for(i=0; i<cells; i++)
        array[i] =  i * (myrank+1.0);

    if(myrank!=0){
        MPI_Send(array, cells, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&array, &resultado, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (myrank == 0) {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<cells; j++){
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                printf("| %lf ",array[i*j]);
            }
        }
        //t1 = MPI_Wtime();
        t2 = MPI_Wtime();
        MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &result);
        printf("master: %d at processor: %s\ntime: %lf\n",myrank, name,t2-t1);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

But all I'm getting is a "Segmentation Fault Error" when I run it. I have read segmentation errors questions but can't diagnose why it's happening to my code.

Thanks in advance.
(and I'm sorry about my bad writing, english is not my first language)

UPDATE: I included a malloc and a free but when running I still have "`mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node Brunos-Air exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).`"

and if I try "`$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpicc -o -Wall -Wextra -g programa3-r1 ./programa3-r1.c`" it gives: "*ld: can't link with a main executable file 'programa3-r1' for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)* "

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger**  `gdb`

Comment: Try to step in your code using a debugger, find the line causing the error and add it to the body of the question.

Comment: As a side note, you likely want yo `MPI_Scatterv()` the `data` array into `array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(id_task = 0; id_task < size; id_task++) {
    //float array[cells];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<cells; i++)
        array[i] =  i * (id_task+1.0);
    MPI_Send(&array[id_task*cells], cells, MPI_FLOAT, id_task, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

you should `MPI_Send()` `array` (aka `&array[0]`) instead of `&array[id_task*cells]`. This is likely the root cause of the crash.

note your program is not correct from an MPI point of view since task 0 `MPI_Send()` to itself and then `MPI_Recv()` from itself. That will likely work just fine with *small* messages, and deadlock with *long* messages. *small* and *long* depend (among other things) on your MPI library, the interconnect used, so you really have to avoid this.

```
if(myrank!=0){
    MPI_Send(array, cells, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

there is no matching `MPI_Recv()` on rank 0, so this could also deadlock.

```
MPI_Reduce(&array, &resultado, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

this sums `array[0]` from all ranks, and store the result in `resultado` on rank 0. i am not sure this is  really what you have in mind (but i do not know what you are trying to achieve, so that might be ok).

Comment: Thank you, sir! It really was wrong from an MPI point of view and I had to implement a MPI_Recv(...) inside a loop to receive data from all tasks. Also corrected the wrong parameter at MPI_Reduce(...)

Answer (score 1):

You have very probably a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow):

```
#define ARRAYSIZE   16000000
```

and later you declare a *local* [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) (on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack))

```
    float   data[ARRAYSIZE];    /* the intial array */
```

this is **unreasonable**. A typical call stack frame should have at most a few kilobytes (since the entire call stack is often limited to a few megabytes or less). You want a 64Mbyte one. You should use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), so declare `float *data = NULL;` and use at appropriate places [`calloc` or `malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (and much later `free`; you should avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)). Don't forget to [check against failure of `calloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551951/841108).

Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger**  `gdb` to check that stack overflow happened.

Read documentation about [GCC command options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You might want to also use something like `-Wstack-usage=2048`

Comment: Like that?

float *data = NULL;
data = (float *) malloc(ARRAYSIZE);

Comment: You'll also need to call (much later) `free`

Comment: mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node Brunos-Air exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).

Comment: and if I try "`$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/mpicc -o -Wall -Wextra -g  programa3-r1 ./programa3-r1.c`" it gives: "_ld: can't link with a main executable file 'programa3-r1' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)_ "

Comment: Thank you, sir! It did work when I tried dynamic allocation `float *data;  /* the intial array */ data = (float *) malloc (sizeof(float)*ARRAYSIZE);`