# c programming more efficient use of big arrays

Tags: c, arrays

How would I make these big arrays more efficient? I am getting a segmentation fault when I add them, but when I remove them the segmentation fault goes away. I have several big arrays like this that are not shown. I need the arrays to be this big to handle the files that I am reading from. In the code below I used stdin instead of the file pointer I would normally use. I also free each big array after use.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    int players_column_counter = 0;
    int players_column1[100000] = {0};
    char *players_strings_line_column2[100000] = {0};
    char *players_strings_line_column3[100000] = {0};
    char *players_strings_line_column4[100000] = {0};
    char *players_strings_line_column5[100000] = {0};
    char *players_strings_line_column6[100000] = {0};
    char line[80] = {0};


    while(fgets(line, 80, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        players_strings_line_column2[players_column_counter] = 
        malloc(strlen("string")+1);

        strcpy(players_strings_line_column2[players_column_counter], 
        "string");
        players_column_counter++;
    }

    free(*players_strings_line_column2);
    free(*players_strings_line_column3);
    free(*players_strings_line_column4);
    free(*players_strings_line_column5);
    free(*players_strings_line_column6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `malloc` (and friends) to allocate dynamically.

Comment: The segmentation fault is most likely due to a Stack Overflow (get the joke?), which is when memory is located over the bounds of a special, small, and fast section of memory reserved for the most important parts of your program. Use malloc to correct this, as @usr said above.

Comment: Free for automatic variables? Interesting idea. You need a C book

Comment: @usr like that?

Comment: @Cppplus1 like that?

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 Yes, the malloc part is OK. But your program as a whole still doesn't make much sense. See the duplicate for some ideas and you can obviously google for more examples.

Comment: You really need to research how to `free` an array of pointers. Generally, you should be calling `free` as many times as you called `malloc` (i.e., you need a loop). `free(*players_strings_line_column2);` will just free the first element of that array, but not the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Read much more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Learn to use [`malloc` and `calloc` and `free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory). Notice that `malloc` and `calloc` (and `realloc`) can fail, and you need to handle that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551951/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234720/841108).

The [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is limited in size (to one or a few megabytes typically; the actual limit is operating system and computer specific). It is unreasonable to have a call frame of more than a few kilobytes. But `calloc` or `malloc` might permit allocation of a few gigabytes (the actual limit depends upon your system), or at least hundreds of megabytes on current laptops or desktops. A local -[automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)- array of more than a few hundreds elements is almost always wrong (and is surely very bad smell).

BTW, if your system has [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), you probably should want to use it (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108)). And likewise for [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) and [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html).

<sup>If your system don't have `getline`, or `strdup`, or `asprintf`, you should consider implementing them, or borrow some free software implementation of them.</sup>

Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb`  (and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (such as [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)s) and of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Study the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) and/or some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)) for inspiration.