# print multiple arrays of diferent type in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to print multiple arrays of different type in ascending order based on the `numbers_column3` value. I have two array of pointers and an array of floats. I would like them to remain grouped together like an excel document with a1, a2, and a3 for the first row. I have three arrays for each column. The code I am showing is just a simple example. I have around 20k values in my arrays currently. Is there a way to avoid the typical bubble sort? That would require a lot of malloc and strcpy operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *q6_tag_strings_line_column1[2000] = {0};
    char *q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[2000] = {0};
    float numbers_column3[2000] = {0};

    q6_tag_strings_line_column1[0] = 
    malloc(strlen("echo")+1);

    strcpy(q6_tag_strings_line_column1[0], 
    "echo");

    q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[0] = 
    malloc(strlen("hi")+1);

    strcpy(q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[0], 
    "hi");

    numbers_column3[0] = 5;

    q6_tag_strings_line_column1[1] = 
    malloc(strlen("how")+1);

    strcpy(q6_tag_strings_line_column1[1], 
    "how");

    q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[1] = 
    malloc(strlen("are")+1);

    strcpy(q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[1], 
    "are");

    numbers_column3[1] = 7;


    q6_tag_strings_line_column1[2] = 
    malloc(strlen("you")+1);

    strcpy(q6_tag_strings_line_column1[2], 
    "you");

    q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[2] = 
    malloc(strlen("what")+1);

    strcpy(q6_nationality_strings_line_column2[2], 
    "what");

    numbers_column3[1] = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is

```
you what 4
echo hi 5
how are 7
```

Comment: Why not use a `struct` with `tag`, `nationality`, and `number` fields, then sort an array of these structures with `qsort()`?

Comment: If you haven't learned about structures yet, then 'parallel arrays' is what you have to work with.  If you've learned about structures, use them; it will make life heaps easier. Also, if you don't have `strdup()` available on your machine, write your own version and use it. It reduces the code dramatically.  (extern char *strdup(const char *str); char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *rv = malloc(len); if (rv != 0) memmove(rv, str); return rv; }` (You could even decide to abort or exit if the `malloc()` fails — that means you don't have to check for error returns.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I learned about structs probably 10 years ago and only use them at most once a year so my memory about them is REALLY fuzzy. I was able to mostly understand Davids with minimal questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements of the three arrays are semantically coupled, why not create a `struct` with `tag`, `nationality`, and `number` fields. This makes explicit the connection between the data elements, and allows an array of such structures to be created and sorted using the standard library `qsort()` function. Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data {
    char *tag;
    char *nationality;
    float number;
};

int compare_Data(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void)
{
    struct Data my_data[] = {
        { .tag = "North America",
          .nationality = "Canadian",
          .number = 3.3 },
        { .tag = "South America",
          .nationality = "Brazilian",
          .number = 5.5 },
        { .tag = "Asia",
          .nationality = "Japanese",
          .number = 1.1 },
    };

    puts("Before sorting:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof my_data / sizeof *my_data; i++) {
        printf("Number:      %f\n"
               "Nationality: %s\n"
               "Tag:         %s\n",
               my_data[i].number,
               my_data[i].nationality,
               my_data[i].tag);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    qsort(my_data,
          sizeof my_data / sizeof *my_data,
          sizeof *my_data,
          compare_Data);

    puts("After sorting:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof my_data / sizeof *my_data; i++) {
        printf("Number:      %f\n"
               "Nationality: %s\n"
               "Tag:         %s\n",
               my_data[i].number,
               my_data[i].nationality,
               my_data[i].tag);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare_Data(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct Data *da = (const struct Data *) a;
    const struct Data *db = (const struct Data *) b;

    return (da->number > db->number) - (da->number < db->number);
}
```

Program output:

```
Before sorting:
Number:      3.300000
Nationality: Canadian
Tag:         North America

Number:      5.500000
Nationality: Brazilian
Tag:         South America

Number:      1.100000
Nationality: Japanese
Tag:         Asia

After sorting:
Number:      1.100000
Nationality: Japanese
Tag:         Asia

Number:      3.300000
Nationality: Canadian
Tag:         North America

Number:      5.500000
Nationality: Brazilian
Tag:         South America
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. I was starting to google for some examples. A struct sounds like it will make life easier.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- This sounds like just the sort of thing that `struct`s are good for, and the library `qsort()` function is efficient, and already written ;)

Comment: can you please refresh my memory on a few things please? What is the `.` for in `.tag = "North America",`? What does this do `sizeof my_data / sizeof *my_data`? Is it better to do `sizeof *my_data` instead of `sizeof my_data` on the third part of the `qsort()`? I was looking at an example where they did it what way http://anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- `.tag` is part of the _designated initializer_ syntax. This allows you to specify which field you are initializing. `sizeof my_data` yields the size of the array `my_data[]` in bytes, while `sizeof *my_data` yields the size of the first element of the array. So, `sizeof my_data / sizeof *my_data` yields the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- the third argument to `qsort()` is the size of each object in the array to be sorted, so `sizeof *my_data` is the correct value, while `sizeof my_data` is not. I will take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: this was the part I was referring to `    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), struct_cmp_by_price);`

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- in the example you linked to, I see that an array of `int`s is sorted, so the third argument to `qsort()` is `sizeof (int)`, since each array element is that size. There is also an example there sorting an array of pointers to strings, where `sizeof (char *)` is used as this is the size of the elements in the array to be sorted.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- finally I see an array of `struct`s being sorted there. In that case they use `sizeof (struct st_ex)`. Note that here `(struct st_ex)` is a parenthesized _type_. In my example I used an _expression_: `sizeof *my_data`. The alternative would be to use `sizeof (struct Data)`, which would also be fine. But I tend to favor the expression version.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- one last thing.... You could substitute `sizeof my_data[0]` for `sizeof *my_data`; I tend to prefer the latter, but this may seem a bit terse to some ;)

Comment: Can you please tell me what I managed to screw up? https://ideone.com/oEXFp9 The first set of printf print as you would expect and second set are null or 0 after the `qsort()`.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 -- in your linked program you have `struct Data my_data[1000];`, which is uninitialized. Then with the call to `qsort()` the code attempts to sort the entire array, even though most values are indeterminate. You could add something like `size_t num_elements = 3;  qsort(my_data, num_elements, sizeof *my_data, compare_Data);` to keep from sorting the whole array. Note that you could instead zero initialize with `struct Data my_data[1000] = { { 0 } };`, but this would result in the zero-entries being sorted to the front of the array.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do a small example to get a feel for this. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Could you respond to this topic when you get a chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993815/c-programming-more-efficient-use-of-big-arrays? I forgot to ask when I originally posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you store the indexes of column3 in another array, then you can print the columns as per indexes.
For eg - during sorting of column 3 store the index as follows so that
new array contains [2,0,1]