# why datetime change to 1st Jan in 16 year ago does not show year part properly?

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to set the date to 1st of Jan 16 years ago from today's date. I used the code

```
DateTime dtm = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
dtm.AddYears(-16);
dtpDOB.Value = dtm;// assign value to date time picker
```

but it shows the date value as 1/1/2014, why this does not set the year part back in 16 years?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` type is a `struct`. Because of that, its properties are [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297115(v=vs.100).aspx) (they can't be changed post-constructor). `struct`s are passed [by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs) in C#.

Because of that, as a few other people have said, you need to reassign the value.

```
dtm = dtm.AddYears(-16);
```

It's just like a typical `string` operation in C#. When you call `string.Replace(string, string)`, you need to capture the return value of the operation. The same is true for LINQ-y `IEnumerable<T>` operations.

Although that said, it seems like you'd be better off to just call the constructor appropriately.

```
dtpDOB.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 16, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
dtm = dtm.AddYears(-16);
```

Just assign the value

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `.AddYears` will return a new `DateTime` object rather than modifying the existing instance. So change your line to

```
dtm = dtm.AddYears(-16);
```