# Why I couldn't change the value of pictureBox1.Location.X directly?

Tags: c#

I want to change the value of pictureBox1.Location. And the result really confuses me!

```
Point player;    
player = pictureBox1.Location;    
player.X += 10; //it works    
pictureBox1.Location.X += 10;//it doesn't work!! Why??
```

so I try this one :

```
pictureBox1.Location = player // it works
```

Could anyone tell me why? I only learnt c# for 1 week with *head first c#*, and I cannot find the answer through the Internet or the book.

Sorry, I didn't make my question clarified. I cannot build

```
pictureBox1.Location.X += 10    .
```

There is an error:

> Cannot modify the return value of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable

I want to know the difference between player.X and pictureBox1.Location.X

Comment: [Why are mutable structs evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) and [Immutability of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608542/immutability-of-structs)

Comment: @Selman22, it's true that you shouldn't create mutable structs, but in this case the OP didn't create it, and he has to work with it...

Comment: I didn't mean to answer his question. but those questions would help him to understand why this is happening.

Comment: You can to set it to anew Point `pictureBox1.Location=new Point(x+10 ,1)`

Comment: Thank you @JAT, It works and very simple.

Answer (score 1):

`Location` is of type `Point`, which is a value type (struct). So when you access `pictureBox1.Location`, it returns a *copy* of the location. Changing `X` on this copy will have no effect on `pictureBox1.Location`, so it's probably not what you want; the compiler detects it and issues an error.

You must think of `Point` as a value, not an object that contains values. The fact that the `X` and `Y` property is unfortunate; writing mutable structs is a pretty bad idea, but `Point` dates back to the first version of .NET, and I guess MS had not yet realized how bad it could be...

Comment: Thank you! But why "player.X += 10" works? Sorry, I didn't make my question clarified. Rather than getting a wrong result, I get an error with "pictureBox1.Location.X += 10" and cannot build it..

Comment: @SunjueLi, because `player` is a variable, so you can access it directly; it doesn't make a copy, unlike accessing the `Location` property. The error you're getting on `pictureBox1.Location.X += 10` is because the compiler knows that it wouldn't do what you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I totally understand it! Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote up (I used to think it's like quora)..

Answer (score 0):

Messagebox also has,
Left (R/W)
Right (R)
Bottom (R)
Top (R/W)

R = Read only
R/W = Read write

You can get the most right side of textbox coordinate x by typing

```
Int right_x = messagebox.Right;
```

Write

```
Messagebox.Left += 10;
```

and it works perfectly.

EDIT:

Source code of Messagebox.Location struct atleast has something like this.

```
Public struct Location { public int x, y; }
```

If you try this

```
messagebox.Location.x += 10;
```

You are trying to modify useless variable, and it's pointless.
Now this is possible

```
Messagebox.Location = new Point(messagebox.Location.x + 10, messagebox.Location.y);
```

But the method I provided earlier is faster, since it doesn't care about y axis.

Comment: You could have edited your other answer.  This just repeats it and adds a little more to it.  In the future, click on the edit link under your post.  Feel free to delete your other answer.

Comment: @LarsTech I actually did edit, somehow it created a new answer. I tried to remove it, but stack exchange won't allow it, not sure why.

Comment: @LarsTech If stack exchange allows you to delete the copy of my answer, please do so :)

Comment: I'm not a moderator, so I can't delete your answer.  But there should be a link under your post to delete.  I'm not aware of any rules against you deleting your own answer, so it should work.

Comment: @LarsTech I see. It's probably because they didn't write function to delete it in Android version, it's my guess. If google chrome has that feature, I will delete it, thanks in advance.